# Which version of PostgreSQL does MapBender require?

Tags: mapbender

I've tested MapBender that comes packaged in OSGeoLive and now want to install it on my Windows 10 Machine. Looking through the requirements on the [Windows installation page](https://doc.mapbender.org/en/installation/installation_windows.html), it seems that MabBender requires PostgreSQL pre version 10

> set up PostgreSQL database (version < 10, https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)
>
> established database for Mapbender configuration
>
> if necessary: own user for access

Can someone confirm that indeed PostgreSQL is required and if yes, what version is needed to run MapBender (3.2.6) on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I had used map bender in the past.
If you need to create an online geo-database you do need PostgreSQL and PostGis to upload your shapes to the database.

I use postgres 12.8, you can download it from here. https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Here is the link to PostGis
http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg12/